# Building a custom field type: How do I render a custom attribute?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco-contour

I'm trying to create a custom field type in Contour (3.0.14) using razor to do the rendering. I created a new class called `CustomTextfield` with an extra `Width` attribute, then a new view in `~/umbraco/Plugins/umbracoContour/Views` called `Fieldtype.customtextfield.cshtml`. What I need to know is: how do I access the `Width` property from the custom view?

Here's my code:

CustomTextfield.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Custom.FieldType {
    public class CustomTextfield : Umbraco.Forms.Core.FieldType {
        public CustomTextfield() { 
            //Provider 
            this.Id = new Guid("b994bc8b-2c65-461d-bfba-43c4b3bd2915"); 
            this.Name = "Custom Textfield"; 
            this.Description = "Renders a html input fieldKey"; //FieldType 
            this.Icon = "textfield.png";
        }

        public System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox tb;
        public List<Object> _value;

        [Umbraco.Forms.Core.Attributes.Setting("Width", description = "Enter the width of the Textfield")]
        public string Width { get; set; }

        public override WebControl Editor {
            get {
                tb.TextMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                tb.CssClass = "text";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Width)) {
                    int width;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(this.Width, out width)) {
                        tb.Width = width;
                    }
                }
                if (_value.Count > 0)
                    tb.Text = _value[0].ToString();

                return tb;
            }
            set { base.Editor = value; }
        }

        public override List<Object> Values {
            get {
                if (tb.Text != "") {
                    _value.Clear();
                    _value.Add(tb.Text);
                }
                return _value;
            }
            set { _value = value; }
        }

        public override string RenderPreview() {
            return
                "<input type=\"text\" id=\"text-content\" class=\"text\" maxlength=\"500\" style=\"" + this.Width + "px\" />";
        }

        public override string RenderPreviewWithPrevalues(List<object> prevalues) {
            return RenderPreview();
        }

        public override bool SupportsRegex {
            get { return true; }
        }

    }
}
```

Fieldtype.customtextfield.cshtml:

```
@model Umbraco.Forms.Mvc.Models.FieldViewModel
<input type="text" name="@Model.Name" id="@Model.Id" class="text" value="@Model.Value" maxlength="500" 
style="@{if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Width)){<text>width:@(Model.Width)px; </text>}}"
@{if(Model.Mandatory || Model.Validate){<text>data-val="true"</text>}}
@{if (Model.Mandatory) {<text> data-val-required="@Model.RequiredErrorMessage"</text>}}
@{if (Model.Validate) {<text> data-val-regex="@Model.InvalidErrorMessage" data-regex="@Model.Regex"</text>}}
/>
```

The code for the view doesn't work because I'm trying to reference the non-existent `Width` property. I couldn't find any examples of custom field types with custom properties using razor. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this. It turns out `FieldViewModel` has an `AdditionalSettings` attribute which is of type `List<FieldSettingViewModel>` which consists of a string `Key` and `Value`

To get my above example to work, I can use the following:

```
@model Umbraco.Forms.Mvc.Models.FieldViewModel
@{
    var widthSetting = Model.AdditionalSettings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key.Equals("Width"));
    string width = (widthSetting == null) ? null : widthSetting.Value;
}
<input type="text" name="@Model.Name" id="@Model.Id" class="text" value="@Model.Value" maxlength="500" 

    style="@{if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width)){<text>width:@(width)px; </text>}}"

    @{if(Model.Mandatory || Model.Validate){<text>data-val="true"</text>}}
    @{if (Model.Mandatory) {<text> data-val-required="@Model.RequiredErrorMessage"</text>}}
    @{if (Model.Validate) {<text> data-val-regex="@Model.InvalidErrorMessage" data-regex="@Model.Regex"</text>}}
/>
```